# How can I reduce page load times in a *VERY UNCONVENTIONAL* C# ASP.NET web forms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, webforms

(I have been at this problem for about 6 months now, so please forgive me if anything about this question does not fit Stack Overflow's guidelines. <strike>I'm pretty sure I'm ok though.</strike> I knew there was a chance of this being too vague, I just wasn't sure.)

Long story short: I have been tasked with improving an absolute demon of an asp.net web application that was developed in 2001. The original programmer did not use a single ASP html object, but instead opted to print *ALL* html, javascript, and css via Response.Write(). All of the .aspx pages are, quite literally, blank - everything is done in the aspx.cs.

Here is an example of what I'm working with, and what 90% of the codebehind looks like:

```
if (Common.IsSuperuser())
{
Response.Write("<div style=\"float:left;padding:5px 5px 5px 25px;\">");
Response.Write("<form action=\"users.aspx?id=" + strUserID + "&siteid=" + thisSite._siteGUID + "\" method=\"post\" style=\"display:inline;\">");
Response.Write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"isClearEmpty\" value=\"true\" />");
Response.Write("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"clearEmptyAccounts\" value=\"Clear Empty Users\" />");
Response.Write("</form>");
Response.Write("</div>");
}
```

Please end me.

One of the major goals is to reduce page load times, which are currently sitting between 4 and 8 seconds. However, when I set two breakpoints at the '{' and '}' of the page_load() function, the time elapsed between them is only ~475ms for any given .aspx page. Where is the other 3500-7500ms coming from?

According to Chrome's console, that time is spent simply waiting for the server. We host dozens of web stores on one server (50+), each store is its own ASP.NET application in it's own directory, and furthermore each store's admin component is also it's own ASP.NET application within it's respective store's directory. Each store/admin combo also has it's own Microsoft Access (yes, you read that right) database. It is, frankly, insane.

The kicker is that the actual store application loads just fine, but the admin side application is always plagued with >5s load times. We also quite often get a plaintext response "Server Too Busy" while on the admin application, but never on the client side store. (Literally zero other information, just a blank, white HTML page that says "Server Too Busy")

Our stores are hosted on a virtual semi-private server by a third party, so let's rule out server settings and hardware for now, as I do not have the ability to change these things. I'm just wondering if there is anything I can do within the boundaries of the application itself to alleviate our administrators' frustrations while I rewrite the entire thing from the ground up.

If there is anything that anyone can suggest, great, I'll try it. If I'm limited by my inability to control server settings, or by the vagueness of this question (I have no more information to go on, sorry), that's fine too.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: You've got yourself quite a hairball here to deal with, but it's not really a problem specific enough to be answered here. My approach is to ensure this is checked into version control, then start arbitrarily deleting things until it speeds up, then incrementally undo the deletions until the problem areas are identified. If it looks slow, slash it out, even with commenting, until you can isolate the performance issues.

Comment: Technically this code "works" by a very loose definition of work, so unless you have a more specific problem it's not really possible to give a specific answer. There's no magic bullet for these.

Comment: In about 2006, I worked on this very code (ok, perhaps not, but it's not as rare as perhaps you think... the style was literally identical). It makes me weep. This sounds like it is more likely to be resource contention in the server. Chucking out strings is easy. I assume the DB access is equally "special". How is it performing? How long are the queries taking? Can you upload a build that reports on the size of the server's ThreadPool? How's that looking?

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought there might be enough specifics here to go on, but I was not sure. This was a last resort, and these answers confirm my situation. I have been doing a little bit of the "comment things out until it's faster" - I'll just have to continue with that tedium.

Comment: Also, @spender the actual db queries themselves aren't bad at all. I had to clean up a few areas but that was basically the first thing I did. I will have to look into how to glean that info off the server in my code, that's a good idea. We did have some problems with the app pool crashing which turned out to be a connection never being closed, but maybe there's more to it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Install [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) for FireBug *or PageSpeed* it will tell you the key things that are slow.

1. Limit your HTTP requests
2. Minimize, compress and combine your JavaScript and CSS files
3. Use CSS Sprites
4. Put script tags at the bottom of the page
5. Compress your images
6. Install Memcache to further reduce the database load,
7. Set up a separate domain or CDN to serve static files.
8. In my experience Access Databases are terrible for more than 4 or 5 concurrent users. **Migrate to SQLExpress** ASAP which has the same 4GB storage limit but it doesn't use the JET engine.

The StringBuilder suggestion I suspect wont make much of a differce because `Response.Write` internally appends strings to a reusable buffer so that it does not suffer the performance overhead of allocating memory, in addition to cleaning that memory up.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I think there are quite a few script areas that I can clean up and move, I hadn't quite thought of that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Access databases are not designed to scale. For example, it maxes out (in theory) at 255 users, but Microsoft's advice is to limit it to 10 users.  Yes, ***ten***.

The wait times may be related to threads blocking while they wait for Access resources to be released.  So, step #1, migrate it to SQL Server or some other database solution that is designed for enterprise use.

> Microsoft Jet has a read-cache that is updated every PageTimeout milliseconds (default is 5000ms = 5 seconds). It also has a lazy-write mechanism that operates on a separate thread to main processing and thus writes changes to disk asynchronously. These two mechanisms help boost performance, but in certain situations that require high concurrency, they may create problems.
>
> Jet can support up to 255 concurrent users, but performance of the file-based architecture can prevent its use for many concurrent users. In general, **it is best to use Jet for 10 or fewer concurrent users.**

Article: [What are the limitations of Microsoft Access?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150511152805/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-limitations-of-ms-access.html)

Comment: I am woefully aware of the limitations of Access, but that actually hasn't been too much of a problem since any given store probably won't have more than 10 concurrent users (It's just businesses ordering branded apparel/items for their employees). Now, one thing I'm not too sure of, is how the app pool handles many access databases on one server. Is it a global connection pool, or does each .mdb have its own? I'll have to do some more google-fu on that. Thanks for pointing me in a direction!

Answer (score 0):

I am not realy sure about this but I would try to add the html markup to a StringBuilder object and call the Response.Write just once with the content of that StringBuilder object... I can imagine that could cause the problems.